# How to reset Subversion $Id$ tag?

Tags: svn

Hey all, I deleted my files from a project I was working on and rechecked it out. However even though my client is configured to recognize $Id$ tags, it is now no longer updating them.

My config file is as follows:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
*.js = svn:keywords=Id
```

And I have ran:

```
find . \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec svn propset svn:keywords Id {} \;
```

Still, it is not updating the $Id$ tags. Do I have to reset these somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a `svn:keywords` property on the file itself inside your source repository?

The autoproperties [auto-props] is only for *new* files and not files already in your Subversion repository. The idea of autoproperties is to automatically attach a property to a *new* file when you do an `svn add`.

To add the `svn:keywords` property, do the following:

```
$ svn propset svn:keywords "Id" $FILE_NAME
$ svn commit -m"Added Id Keyword to file"
```

Comment: Hi, yes it is on the file itself. I noticed if I reset the $Id to $Id$ it works.

Comment: Ah! That you didn't mention. Yes, you need dollar signs on BOTH sides of the string. That'll fix it.